# Selecting md5sums from a text file and remove duplicates in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, duplicates, md5sum

I've used the find command and created a file called Duplicates.txt full of the md5sums of a bunch of images.

How do I go about finding the duplicate md5's in the file, and then using those to remove the duplicates from the archive?

edit: I can't use fdupes.

Comment: `md5sum [filenames] | awk 'x[$1]++'` gives you the list of duplicates (the first appearance of each set of duplicates is excluded though).

Comment: An alternative is to use a program that scans the directory and finds duplicates files (like `fdupes`) - there is a big list [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3865/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files) of alternatives if you need them.

Comment: Check the `fdupes` program.

Answer (score 0):

```
sort Duplicates.txt|uniq -c|grep -v '^ *1 '
```

Comment: Sorry, that won't work...  they'd have different filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you made your file `Duplicates` in a manner similar to this:

```
find ./dupimgs -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum > dupes.txt
```

Then you could easily extract the files that are unique with this one-liner:

```
sort dupes.txt  | uniq --check-chars=40 --count | cut -d' ' -f 10
```

These are the files you'll want to keep. I suggest moving them in another directory and then remove the directory that is now full of copies:

```
sort dupes.txt  | uniq --check-chars=40 --count | cut -d' ' -f 10 | xargs -I {} mv {} ./originals
rm -rf ./dupimgs
```

Remark: I used `sha1sum` rather than `md5sum`. That means the length of the digests will be different. For `sha1sum` it's 40 characters. For `md5sum`, [it's 32 hexadecimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). So you'll want to change the `40` in the above commands to match the length of the hexadecimal strings that are returned by whichever hashing function you've used.

Answer (score 0):

There is some impressive bash-fu behind fslint's duplicate search engine script "[findup](https://code.google.com/p/fslint/source/browse/trunk/fslint/findup)"; the bit you are interested in is around line 185.

I would normally put in a plug for [rmlint](https://rmlint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but it looks like you are looking for a purely bash solution.